"Error while copying content to a stream" exception with streamed Multipart request
I have a .NET 6 application that sends some files and some associated data to a server. The following code is responsible for submitting that data:
public async Task SubmitData(
    Data data,
    CancellationToken cancelToken = default
)
{
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    foreach (var file in data.Files)
    {
        var stream = File.Open(
            Path.Join(data.Dir, file.Name),
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete
        );
        content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "files", file.FullPath);
    }

    content.Add(new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data)), "data");
    var response = await uploadHttpClient.PostAsync(url, content, cancelToken);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

This seems to work fine in general, but in one case the application fails every time with a "Error while copying content to a stream" exception in that code. This is on a Windows computer I don't control and don't have direct access to. There are no related errors in the logs of the server it is talking to.
I'm trying to understand the possible causes here so I can debug this problem. It is not a transient network problem, the error is completely reproducible and happens every time on this particular computer. It is also not a general connection issue, other HTTP requests to that server work fine from this PC.
The most common cause for this error seem to be mistakes around disposing streams. I know the disposal is not entirely correct in this code, it does not dispose the individual file streams and I intend to fix that. But a simple "using" statement on the File.Open line here actually does produce exactly the same error as it will lead to disposal of the streams before they're sent to the server. So I don't see how not disposing them could cause this particular issue.
Before this code runs the files in question are read in their entirety, and no exception is thrown there. So I don't think permissions issues could cause this error as they should be triggered in the earlier code.
I'm wondering if the FileAccess part could cause this error. Is it possible for this part to fail with this particular error message? Something like e.g. failing to open the file because some other process is accessing it? The code intentionally has very liberal FileShare settings to avoid blocking any other code that handles those files. Could another program still cause this and produce exactly this error?
As this error only occurs in an environment I don't control and cannot access directly I'm mostly trying to understand all aspects here in order to make this code more resilient even if I cannot reproduce this particular issue exactly. Are there any possible causes I missed? Any ways for me to gather better information about possible causes of this error? Anything else to do to make this code more robust?

Most of the time when i have similar problems it's because the FileStream is not in the right position. I would start by adding a stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); before you add anything and see if you still get the same problem.

@ChrisFromTheBlock I'm opening the stream right there in the code and never doing anything else other than passing it to the StreamContent for the request. How could the position of the stream be wrong here?
